# Error: No permission to modify static procedure

Tags: prolog

I stored facts like these:

```
 %           name,              price , range
 processor('Intel Core i3 8100', 104, 'low_range').
 motherboard('Asrock B350m', 65, 'low_range').
 ram('Ballistix Sport 4GB 2666mhz', 50, 'low_range').
 case('Sharkoon s25-s', 40, 'low_range').
 ali('Cougar VTX 450w', 43, 'low_range').
 video_card('Nvidia GTX1050 2GB', 130, 'middle_range').
 ssd('Adata SP580 120GB', 40, 'low_range').
 monitor('Asus VC239H Monitor 23"', 163, 'middle_range').
 hdd('Toshiba 1TB 7200rpm', 32, 'middle_range').
```

I'm trying to generate all configurations from these facts, I'm using findall like below:

```
findall(P-M-R-C-A-V-S-D-H,
(processor(P,Proc_price,Price_range),motherboard(M,Motherboard_price, 
Price_range), ram(R,Ram_price,Price_range),case(C,Case_price, 
Price_range),ali(A,Ali_price, Price_range),video_card(V,Vga_price, 
Price_range),ssd(S,Ssd_price, Price_range), monitor(D,Monitor_price, 
Price_range),hdd(H,Hdd_price, Price_range)),Res).
```

but I get these errors:

```
Warning:  Singleton variables: [Proc_price,Motherboard_price,Ram_price,Case_price,Ali_price,Vga_price,Ssd_price,Monitor_price,Hdd_price,Res]
ERROR:  No permission to modify static procedure `findall/3'
        Defined at c:/program files/swipl/boot/bags.pl:88
```

I should generate all configurations for low_range, all configuration for middle_range and all configuration checking if total components price with a value that is stored in 'price' variable

Answer (score 1):

*Defining* and *querying* Prolog programs are (mostly) separate activities that take place in separate environments.

Your question starts with *definitions* that you write in a Prolog source file. That's fine.

But you presumably want to *run* the `findall/3` query and observe its results.  You do not write queries in source files; you type them into Prolog's interactive prompt. The somewhat obscure "No permission to modify static procedure `findall/3`" error message says that Prolog encountered something involving `findall/3` in a place where it expected predicate definitions, i.e., in a source file. But you didn't mean your use of `findall/3` to be a definition of `findall/3`.

Your program "works" for me if I add *only* the component definitions into a source file (and fix the missing period on the first line) and then run the `findall/3` query from Prolog's interactive prompt:

```
$ swipl -q -s foo.pl 
?- findall(P-M-R-C-A-V-S-D-H,
|    (processor(P,Proc_price,Price_range),motherboard(M,Motherboard_price, 
|    Price_range), ram(R,Ram_price,Price_range),case(C,Case_price, 
|    Price_range),ali(A,Ali_price, Price_range),video_card(V,Vga_price, 
|    Price_range),ssd(S,Ssd_price, Price_range), monitor(D,Monitor_price, 
|    Price_range),hdd(H,Hdd_price, Price_range)),Res).
Res = [].
```

Some tips: Writing such huge goals, and such huge `findall/3` goals in particular, is a pain. Always (*for experts only: almost always*) put the goal you want to pass to `findall/3` into a separate, nicely named predicate, e.g.:

```
configuration(P, M, R, C, A, V, S, D, H) :-
    processor(P, _Proc_price, Price_range),
    motherboard(M, _Motherboard_price, Price_range),
    ram(R, _Ram_price, Price_range),
    case(C, _Case_price, Price_range),
    ali(A, _Ali_price, Price_range),
    video_card(V, _Vga_price, Price_range),
    ssd(S, _Ssd_price, Price_range),
    monitor(D, _Monitor_price, Price_range),
    hdd(H, _Hdd_price, Price_range).
```

You can then run this as:

```
?- findall(P-M-R-C-A-V-S-D-H, configuration(P, M, R, C, A, V, S, D, H), Res).
Res = [].
```

Isn't that much nicer? This also makes it easier to test this predicate and understand why it has no results.

You also need to understand what singleton variable warnings are and why you should fix them before doing anything else. (I have taken care of this for you in the predicate above.)

Comment: Sorry but I'm a beginner in Prolog, I got no errors now but I should get all the configurations to print them to the user, how I could do that? I actually get Res = [ ], like you said earlier

Comment: That's because the goal `configuration(P, M, R, C, A, V, S, D, H)` has no solutions. You need to understand why. What is the role of the `Price_range` variable?

Comment: I ask the user for the price range of the configuration and I store the answer in a variable. If the user want to generate low cost configurations I should get configurations where Price_range = 'low_range' for each component

Comment: @Nicola: Right. Part of the problem is that some of the components you have are `low_range`, others `middle_range`, but there is no one range shared by all components. If you need more help with that, please open another question; I will now change the title of this one because the immediate problem was the "no permission to modify" error.